# JavaFx TableView - ScrollTo and scrollToOffSet is taking long time

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am loading 3L records in table using JavaFx TableView concept. I could figure out some performance issue when apply the scrollTo().
Initially I tried VirtualFlow -> scrollToOffset() and taking more time. Then I tried VirtualFlow -> scrollTo(). This is comparitively giving better
performance. But, even scrollTo() is taking 10 seconds to load the page.

I red in forum, scrollTo() is taking less time than scrollToOffset() but not exact position. This is fine.

My requirement is, need to focus last scroll position(swith from one page to another page). Please give me a hint to resolve this issue.
I need to achieve the scroll position as well as better performance.

Software Details:

```
JRE Version - 1.8
JavaFx Jar - jfxrt.jar (Taking from JRE Version 1.8)
```

My Code...

```
TableView<TYPE> m_tableView = new TableView<TYPE>();
m_tableView.getStyleClass().add("DataGrid-Table");
m_tableView.layout(); // Always taking 15 seconds
TableViewSkin<?> tableskin = (TableViewSkin<?>) m_tableView.getSkin();
VirtualFlow virtualFlow = (VirtualFlow) tableskin.getChildren().get(1);
//virtualFlow.scrollToOffset(50000); // Taking 50 seconds to load the page
virtualFlow.scrollTo(50000); // Taking 10 seconds to load the page
```

Comment: Maybe it is possible to pull just ScrollBar from your screen and in this ScrollBar you can use method setValue() - range between 0.0(top) - 1.0(bottom), its my idea

Comment: What OS are you using? What language or languages are displayed in the table?